# Using document.image to print JSON image element to browser

Tags: json, document.write

I have a JSON that I have loaded string and images into but can't work out how to print the images to the browser.

If "document.write(diary_1938[pageRef].date_1);" prints the strings to browser, what is the equivalent code for the image?  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add a little more of your code to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do?   There are many JavaScript libraries that make this thing much, much easier client-side, as they allow direct DOM manipulation with ease.  I use Dojo; jQuery is very popular.

It sounds like what you want to do is generate an image tag to reference the image.

For example, something similar to

```
document.write("<img src='img.png' height='10' width='20'>");
```

Of course, document.write is not a robust practice--direct DOM manipulation with or without the utility  library of your choice is usually a better method.